# Слайдер контейнеров выходит за пределы длины массива

Tags: javascript

пределы листания контейнеров не срабатывают.  Массив elements имеет 3 элемента. 
P.S. только учусь, к элегантности не стремился.

```
let elArr = [];

let pusher = elArr.push(document.querySelectorAll('#scr>div'));
let elements = Array.from(elArr[0]);
let slider = {
  frame: 0,
  set: function(element){
    let container = document.getElementById('scr');
    container = element.style.visibility='visible';
  },

  init: function(){
    this.set(elements[this.frame]);
  },

  left: function(){
    elements[this.frame].style.visibility='hidden';
    this.frame--;
    if(this.frame<0)
    this.frame == elements.length - 1;
    this.set(elements[this.frame]);
  },

  right: function(){
    elements[this.frame].style.visibility='hidden';
    this.frame++;
    if(this.frame>elements.length)
    this.frame = 0;
    this.set(elements[this.frame]);
  }

};

window.onload = function(){
  slider.init();
}
```

Comment: не вижу вызовов `left` и `right`

Comment: в html к button прикреплен onclick="slider.right()"

Comment: https://codepen.io/dev_null/pen/WYREWW
ссылка на пример

Comment: проблема с условиями и присваиванием `this.frame == elements.length - 1;` и `if(this.frame>elements.length)`

Comment: точно, в left проглядел, спасибо. в right не совсем понял, если не сложно, можно чуть подробнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обработчике левой кнопки опечатка, вместо присваивания указано сравнение:

```
this.frame == elements.length - 1;
```

из-за этого, не смотря на условие, значение `frame` не сбрасывается, а продолжает уменьшаться. Как следствие - ошибка при попытке доступа к отрицательному элементу массива.

`elements[this.frame]` начинает возвращать `undefined`, и попытка взять у него `style` - приводит к исключению.

---

В обработчике правой кнопки указано неверное условие.

```
if(this.frame>elements.length)
```

Оно сбрасывает значение `frame`, когда текущее значение больше количества элементов, однако, так как индексирование элементов начинается с 0, когда `frame` равен `elements.length` - значение опять будет `undefined` и исключение описанное выше. Из-за этого значение `frame` никогда не сбрасывается.

Для решения нужно либо изменить условие на сравнение

```
if(this.frame==elements.length)
```

либо проверять не строго:

```
if(this.frame>=elements.length)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогли